# Do I need a concurrent hash map if each thread inserts unique keys?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

From what I understand a concurrent hash map from Java 5 onwards gives you a thread safe hash map that does not use blocking access for iterators and updates (if a concurrency level is sufficient).

Given the following conditions:

1. Inserts only happen once (during application initialisation).
2. Each thread gets a set of keys to insert that are not shared by any other thread.
3. Updates never happen.
4. Selects only happen once the application initialisation is over.

would I be better off with simple hash maps?

My understanding is that I will probably be better off because my keys won't clash --that I can guarantee. But is it possible that the Java implementation will screw things up in the hash buckets by say assigning the same bucket to two different keys?

Comment: Why not simply use a `ConcurrentHashMap` if in doubt?

Comment: @MonsterTruck: If this is only on startup, how much is the contention really hurting you?

Comment: @MonsterTruck: Just for the insert phase? There's no way that 50,000 contended inserts would cost half an hour. I strongly suspect something else is going on. To what extent can you isolate the start-up phase to test it in various ways?

Comment: @MonsterTruck: Cracking. I'd be very surprised if it took more than a second :)

Comment: @MonsterTruck: Right - that's the point; the time taken just for the insertion - whether contended or not - should be absolutely trivial. That's what makes me think there was something else going on in your "less than 10 minutes" vs "more than 40 minutes" scenario.

Comment: @MonsterTruck inserting 50k in a map, even under high contention (1000 threads) takes 80 ms on my machine... Note: using a HashMap instead takes approximately the same amount of time (but is not thread safe). Either you have a lot more threads (which would make no sense) or something else is preventing your code from progressing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're inserting using multiple threads, even if the keys are different, you should definitely use `ConcurrentHashMap` or synchronize the inserts. Plain `HashMap` *simply isn't safe* for concurrent writes. Suppose two threads each need to expand the internal table at the same time... even though they're using different keys, that's a fundamentally problematic situation.

Now if you really *really* have good evidence that using a `ConcurrentHashMap` for the rest of your application lifetime causes a problem (and I very much doubt that it does), you could perhaps build a concurrent hash map to start with, the convert it to a `HashMap` (or even an immutable collection from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)) in a single thread, making sure there's a happens-before barrier between "final map is published" and "threads read final map".

Comment: +1 The only way to avoid using a ConcurrentHashMap is for each thread to be updating a different Map which is only used by that thread.

Comment: OP said inserts only happen at startup. If the Map is safely published, and only after all inserts, then it should be fine. I don't believe HashMap modifies any fields on reads.

Comment: @yshavit: Yes, but he gave the distinct impression that the map is being populated by multiple threads - *that's* what's unsafe.

Comment: Oh, yeah I missed bullet #2.

Answer (score 2):

If you have independant keys across threads, you could consider independant Maps.  If this is an option, each thread can have its own HashMap which doesn't need to be thread safe provided it is only used by one thread.

Comment: If this is an option, it should be the fastest.  You should *only* use a shared ConcurrentHashMap only if you need to share the data across threads.